# Comparing vertices with specific attributes

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I tried finding a solution, but since I am not that familiar with R, I'm not sure if I used the best key words searching.

I have an igraph where vertices have attributes(*positions, wealth*) and I'm trying to compare the *wealth* of those vertices that have *positions == "Manager"*.

### Edit

I'm not only comparing the *wealth* but also another attribute: *constraint*. Also I tried to do the make this reproducible:

```
library(igraph)  
M <- matrix(c( 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,   
           0, 0, 1, 0, 0,   
           1, 1, 0, 0, 1,   
           0, 1, 0, 0, 0,   
           0, 1, 1, 0, 0), nrow = 5, byrow=TRUE)                   
g <- graph.adjacency(M, mode = "undirected")  


V(g)$position <- c("Manager", "Manager", "Other", "Other", "Other")  
V(g)$wealth <- c("12", "16", "16", "4", "29")  
V(g)$constraint <- constraint(g)
```

What I want to do is to see a table with the *wealth* and *constraint* of the Managers only.

### Edit 2

@G5W offered this solution which works perfectly:

```
cbind(V(g)$wealth, V(g)$constraint)[V(g)$position == "Manager"]
```

Comment: We indeed need that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. At the very least it will increase your chances to get an (good) answer. An extra question would be: how do you want to compare this wealth? Or perhaps what you want our help with is just extracting these values and you are going to do the rest?

Comment: https://github.com/thomasp85/tidygraph

Comment: What do you mean `I'm trying to compare the wealth of those vertices that have positions == "Manager"`? Do you want a summary of the distribution of wealth?

Comment: @Julius thank you for that link. I edited the original question. Afterwards I want to see if there is a correlation, but for now I just want to get an overview

Comment: @G5W Sorry, that wasn't very precise of me. I think the best would be a table

Comment: Does `cbind(V(g)$wealth, V(g)$constraint)[V(g)$position == "Manager",]` meet your needs?

Comment: @G5W It does! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking. For this sort of thing, I prefer to use the dplyr package (as part of the tidyverse) because it is usually followed with further wrangling.

Let's say that your data is stored in the dataframe `df`. We can then do the following:

```
df %>%
filter(position == "Manager")
```

This returns all Manager entries.

Alternatively, using the base package, you can use

```
df[df$position == "Manager",]
```

I should add that I'm not familiar with igraph and so for a better answer, sample data should be provided.